# ElasticSearch is swapping

Tags: elasticsearch, swap

I have launch my new site today and have problems with the SWAP of ElasticSearch. I don't know how to fix it because I have give enought heap memory for each of the 2 nodes, but somehow, there are problems.

I am attaching the previews from HQ. Can someone help me?

[image]
[image]

---- config /etc/elasticsearch.yml ---

```
cluster.name: xxx
node.name: xxx
node.data: true
node.master: true

bootstrap.mlockall: true
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000

index.merge.policy.merge_factor: 5
index.merge.policy.segments_per_tier: 10

# Bulk pool
threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 1000
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 30000

# Index pool
threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 1000
threadpool.index.queue_size: 10000

index.cache.query.enable: true
indices.cache.query.size: 15%

index.cache.field.expire: 1h
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 15%
indices.fielddata.cache.expire : 1h
indices.cache.filter.size: 15%
index.store.type: mmapfs
transport.tcp.compress: true;

network.bind_host: xxxx
network.publish_host: xxxx
network.host: xxxx
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxxx"]
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 10s
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
http.max_content_length: 500mb
index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation: false

index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 10s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 5s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 2s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 500ms

script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
index.max_result_window: 40000
```

--- config /etc/default/elasticsearch -----

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=5g
```

---- JAVA process -----
/usr/bin/java -Xms5g -Xmx5g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.1.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start -Des.pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch

---- node info ----
{"cluster_name":"xxxxx_search","nodes":{"Tze_hXZ2SwqQIvg4YWOcMg":{"timestamp":1460563870399,"name":"xxxxx-slave-1","transport_address":"xxxx:9301","host":"xxxxx","ip":["xxxxx:9301","NONE"],"jvm":{"timestamp":1460563870399,"uptime_in_millis":17908517,"mem":{"heap_used_in_bytes":2679603328,"heap_used_percent":50,"heap_committed_in_bytes":5333843968,"heap_max_in_bytes":5333843968,"non_heap_used_in_bytes":105721416,"non_heap_committed_in_bytes":108711936,"pools":{"young":{"used_in_bytes":15540664,"max_in_bytes":279183360,"peak_used_in_bytes":279183360,"peak_max_in_bytes":279183360},"survivor":{"used_in_bytes":2730400,"max_in_bytes":34865152,"peak_used_in_bytes":34865152,"peak_max_in_bytes":34865152},"old":{"used_in_bytes":2661332264,"max_in_bytes":5019795456,"peak_used_in_bytes":3813217632,"peak_max_in_bytes":5019795456}}},"threads":{"count":56,"peak_count":63},"gc":{"collectors":{"young":{"collection_count":1170,"collection_time_in_millis":38743},"old":{"collection_count":4,"collection_time_in_millis":220}}},"buffer_pools":{"direct":{"count":61,"used_in_bytes":15744627,"total_capacity_in_bytes":15744627},"mapped":{"count":85,"used_in_bytes":4319218096,"total_capacity_in_bytes":4319218096}}}},"DrG535FuQKygzKlSCAWwLw":{"timestamp":1460563870399,"name":"xxxxx-master-1","transport_address":"xxxxx:9300","host":"xxxx","ip":["xxxxx:9300","NONE"],"attributes":{"master":"true"},"jvm":{"timestamp":1460563870399,"uptime_in_millis":17912689,"mem":{"heap_used_in_bytes":2315059272,"heap_used_percent":43,"heap_committed_in_bytes":5333843968,"heap_max_in_bytes":5333843968,"non_heap_used_in_bytes":118353088,"non_heap_committed_in_bytes":121683968,"pools":{"young":{"used_in_bytes":172840784,"max_in_bytes":279183360,"peak_used_in_bytes":279183360,"peak_max_in_bytes":279183360},"survivor":{"used_in_bytes":2480072,"max_in_bytes":34865152,"peak_used_in_bytes":34865152,"peak_max_in_bytes":34865152},"old":{"used_in_bytes":2139738416,"max_in_bytes":5019795456,"peak_used_in_bytes":3826731840,"peak_max_in_bytes":5019795456}}},"threads":{"count":59,"peak_count":71},"gc":{"collectors":{"young":{"collection_count":1368,"collection_time_in_millis":47571},"old":{"collection_count":5,"collection_time_in_millis":270}}},"buffer_pools":{"direct":{"count":71,"used_in_bytes":24539898,"total_capacity_in_bytes":24539898},"mapped":{"count":84,"used_in_bytes":4318926707,"total_capacity_in_bytes":4318926707}},"classes":{"current_loaded_count":9552,"total_loaded_count":9695,"total_unloaded_count":143}}}}}

---- node process ---

{"cluster_name":"xxxx_search","nodes":{"Tze_hXZ2SwqQIvg4YWOcMg":{"name":"xxxx-slave-1","transport_address":"xxxx:9301","host":"xxxx","ip":"xxxx","version":"2.3.1","build":"bd98092","http_address":"xxxx:9201","process":{"refresh_interval_in_millis":1000,"id":25686,"mlockall":false}},"DrG535FuQKygzKlSCAWwLw":{"name":"xxxx-master-1","transport_address":"xxxx:9300","host":"xxxx","ip":"xxxx","version":"2.3.1","build":"bd98092","http_address":"xxxx:9200","attributes":{"master":"true"},"process":{"refresh_interval_in_millis":1000,"id":25587,"mlockall":false}}}}

Thanks!

Comment: Set `bootstrap.mlockall: true` on all nodes and have your min heap size (Xms) and max heap size (Xmx) set to the same value. In this way, the OS will not swap the heap memory of the java process running ES. The recommended approach, though, is to disable swapping altogether on that system.

Comment: Also, the swap you see there you don't know if it comes from ES or from other process on your system. But, my recommendations above still stand. If you can, disable swapping on the machines running ES.

Comment: hey Andrei, the ES is running on the same machine like the other stuff: MySQL, Apache etc. At this moment I can not disable it.
I am positng you the config of the nodes as edit. What are this min and max heapsize?

Comment: More details about min and max sizes for heap: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#heap-sizing

Comment: Provide the output of `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/jvm"`

Comment: Please, the output of `GET /_nodes/process`

Comment: ok all info is there :-)

Comment: Strange why is this false: "process":{

    "refresh_interval_in_millis":1000,
    "id":25587,
    "mlockall":false
}, can this be the problem? But in my .yml file I am setting it to true: bootstrap.mlockall: true

Comment: Yes, it can fail to be set. This should be visible in the logs during the startup. Take a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#setup-configuration-memory) for reasons and possible solutions.

Comment: any luck with the mlockall setup?

Comment: yes I have enable LimitMEMLOCK=infinity and MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited. The Refresh and Flush are now ok, but there is still Swapping.

Comment: On both nodes I have: "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 9577,
        "mlockall" : true
      }

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7vdTJgQQ

Comment: Good. That's all you can do from ES point of view regarding swapping.